# Issue with file_get_contents encoding

Tags: php, utf

I'm getting `file_get_contents(uri)` and getting back a Json that I'm unable to encode.

I tried several encodings and `str_replace` but I don't quite understand what the issue is.

This is the start of my json with `file_get_contents`:

`string(67702) "��{"localidades"`

I know it's finding unknown characters and that's what the ? are for, but I don't understand how to solve it.

I've tried this but to no avail

```
    if(substr($s, 0, 2) == chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE)){
      return substr($s,3);
    }
    else{
      return $s;
    }
   }
```

This is xxd | head from terminal

```
00000000: fffe 7b00 2200 6c00 6f00 6300 6100 6c00  ..{.".l.o.c.a.l.
00000010: 6900 6400 6100 6400 6500 7300 2200 3a00  i.d.a.d.e.s.".:.
00000020: 2000 5b00 7b00 2200 6900 6400 4c00 6f00   .[.{.".i.d.L.o.
00000030: 6300 6100 6c00 6900 6400 6100 6400 2200  c.a.l.i.d.a.d.".
00000040: 3a00 2000 3300 2c00 2200 6c00 6f00 6300  :. .3.,.".l.o.c.
00000050: 6100 6c00 6900 6400 6100 6400 2200 3a00  a.l.i.d.a.d.".:.
00000060: 2000 2200 4200 7500 6500 6e00 6f00 7300   .".B.u.e.n.o.s.
00000070: 2000 4100 6900 7200 6500 7300 2200 2c00   .A.i.r.e.s.".,.
00000080: 2200 6900 6400 5000 7200 6f00 7600 6900  ".i.d.P.r.o.v.i.
00000090: 6e00 6300 6900 6100 2200 3a00 2000 2200  n.c.i.a.".:. .".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is UTF-16LE in which each codepoint is encoded as at least two bytes, even "basic ASCII". The first two bytes of the document are the Byte Order Mark [BOM] that declares in what byte-order [endian] those codepoints are encoded

```
$input = "\xff\xfe{\x00}\x00"; // UTF-16-LE with BOM

function convert_utf16($input, $charset=NULL) {
    // if your data has no BOM you must explicitly define the charset.
    if( is_null($charset) ) {
        $bom = substr($input, 0, 2);
        switch($bom) {
            case "\xff\xfe":
                $charset = "UTF-16LE";
                break;
            case "\xfe\xff":
                $charset = "UTF-16BE";
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception("No encoding specified, and no BOM detected");
                break;
        }
        $input = substr($input, 2);
    }
    return mb_convert_encoding($input, "UTF-8", $charset);
}

$output = convert_utf16($input);

var_dump(
    $output,
    bin2hex($output),
    json_decode($output, true)
);
```

Output:

```
string(2) "{}"
string(4) "7b7d"
array(0) {
}
```

It's also worth noting that using anything other than UTF-8 to encode JSON makes it invalid JSON, and you should tell whoever is giving you this data to fix their app.

Comment: Ok, this one worked. I'm not sure what's diferrent, I've tried this several times, removing 2 Chars, then converting to UTF-8, but I'm glad I was able to use `json_decode` to create a PHP Object.
Why are you using **/xff/xfe/**, I saw some others using **/0ff/0fe**.
And is there a way to detect encoding in PHP? I tried using `mb_detect_encoding()` even specifying the encoding and couldn't make it work.

Thanks @Sammitch, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your function only works if I don't send the Charset. Unless the code `$input = substr($input, 2);` is executed, `mb_convert_encoding()` won't work. It would seem there's something else going on with the file I'm receiving.

Comment: Just send it through as-is with no charset specified. It will detect the charset from the BOM automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is `UTF-16 LE`. The `fffe` at the beginning is called a `BOM`. You can use `iconv`:

```
$data = iconv( 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $data);
```

And now you have a `UTF-8` with `BOM`. Which i think will work with `json_decode`, because `PHP` seems to handle it. Still, if you want to remove the `BOM`, which you should (see @Sammitch comment), you can use this one as well:

```
$data = preg_replace("/^pack('H*','EFBBBF')/", '', $data);
```

I recreated a part of your file and i get this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/utf16le.json');
$data = preg_replace("/^pack('H*','EFBBBF')/", '', iconv( 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $data));
print_r(json_decode($data));
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [localidades] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idLocalidad] => 3
                    [localidad] => Buenos Aires
                )

        )

)
```

And from `xxd`:
[image]

Comment: Warning: If you don't strip the BOM from the input document you will get an output document that still contains a BOM. While the UTF-8 BOM is _kinda-sorta_ permissible in permissible in some contexts, it will break in others. Others including strict JSON parsers as the BOM is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: This option was giving me strange things like: ```string(101364) "笀∀氀漀挀愀氀椀搀愀搀攀猀∀㨀``` when I used iconv(), and it wasn't working at all later, because I have no ide what happened with the iconv() thought I have a slight direction when looking at php.net

Comment: if it is not sensible data, can you share the complete json so i can try it ?

Comment: Sure, https://ic7.co/clientes/00081/00081.json it's just weather information.
Like I said in Sammitch reply
**Your function only works if I don't send the Charset. Unless the code `$input = substr($input, 2);` is executed, `mb_convert_encoding()` won't work. It would seem there's something else going on with the file I'm receiving**

Comment: there must be something else wrong because i just tried: `$data = file_get_contents('https://ic7.co/clientes/00081/00081.json');  $data = iconv( 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $data);   print_r(json_decode($data));` And it works.... Can you try the same exact code ?

Answer (score -1):

The file you try to process is encoded in UTF-16, which isn’t natively supported by PHP. So, in order to process it, you’ll have to remove BOM header first (first two bytes) and then convert encoding to UTF-8 using iconv or mbstring.